# Local parametrization, the half-sphere ${S^3}_+$ and rotations

Tags: differential-topology, rotations, quaternions, parametrization

I am reading the book "Robot Control: The task function approach" by Samson et al. (1991), and they're going through some of the math of why $SO(3)$ is difficult to parametrize. They say (paraphrased for clarity):

> Consider the open half-sphere $S_+^3 = \{(\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)\in S^3 | \lambda_0 > 0\}$. This can be mapped to the open subset of rotations with angle not equal to $\pi$. Denoting by $Ret$ the subset of rotations with angle $\pi$, the mapping is a bijective local diffeomorphism from $S^3_+$ onto $\{SO(3)-Ret\}$, it is a diffeomorphism.

Where the set $S^3$ is the set of unitary quaternions: $S^3 = \{(\lambda_0, \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)\in\mathbb{R}^4 \text{ }|\text{ }\sqrt{\lambda_0^2+\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+
\lambda_3^2}=1\}$.

This is fine, but then they say:

> We do not yet have a local parametrization because $S^3_+$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Which I can't quite understand. If $\phi: S_+^3 \rightarrow \{SO(3)-Ret\}$ is a diffeomorphism, isn't it a parametrization? Are there other requirements than just being a bijective local diffeomorphism for something to be a parametrization?

Comment: A parametrization to the author is, presumably, a map whose domain must be an open subset of a Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: So there's no general definition in differential topology for local parametrizations and it is up to the author to define what sort of requirements are on it? (Note: Pressed enter before I finished the comment if you saw the previous comment)

Comment: I'm not a differential topologist so I was hedging when I mentioned the author in my previous comment. But googling `"local parametrization" differential topology` and $\sf ctrl$+$\sf f$ing "parametrization" in the first three textbook pdfs reveals the same definition every time, the one the author here is using (the author's definition being evident from the context you've provided).

Comment: Yep, you're right. The term seems to be used that way elsewhere, must just be assumed knowledge by the author.